# RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable is set to false on application start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
                        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

                        string logsDir = this.GetLoggingPath();
}

private string GetLoggingPath()
{
                        var agentDataDirPath = Path.GetTempPath();

                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Role Environment is available : {0}", RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable));

                        // If running in Azure use default local storage  
                        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Trace.WriteLine("Getting the agentDataDir location");
                                agentDataDirPath = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(agentDataDirStorage).RootPath;
                            }
                            catch (RoleEnvironmentException exp)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException(exp);
                            }
                        }

                        return agentDataDirPath;
}
```

Even when my cloud service is running on azure RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable is false. My service is running on IIS 8.5 and it is running under Network Service.

Any idea what am i doing wrong here. Also when i remote in and change the web.config a bit by adding space then IIS RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable is evaluated to true.

Also i am using Azure version 2.5

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug that causes `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` to always return `false` on the emulator, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695609/roleenvironment-isavailable-is-useless-returns-true-when-invoked-by-code-not-hosted-in-azure-emulator for more information.

You could do something like the following until the bug is fixed:

```
if ( RoleEnvironment.IsEmulator || RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
{
// Role is available
}
```

Comment: Small edit : RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated. Will try the solution mentioned by you and update the thread

Comment: Getting this error:
[InvalidOperationException: the role environment has not been initialized]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_IsEmulated() +150

Comment: Also the webrole is already running on Azure and not on my local machine. Steps that i did was deployed my cspkg and csfg using manage.windowsazure.com. I invoke the url from browser. Remote into the machine and check the trace logs and see RoleEnvironment is false. Edit Web.config a bit to make sure Application_Start is called again and then RoleEnvironment is set to true.

Comment: `RoleEnvironment` may not be available in `Application_Start()` as it is unrelated to Azure, could you perhaps use the WebRole.cs `Onstart` event? See this discussion for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680007/whats-the-difference-between-the-webrole-onstart-event-and-application-start

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
if ( RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable && RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
{
     // we are running the workerrole locally in debug 
}
```